# Arabic Text in TextView gets its last letter cut off

Tags: android, arabic

I have a `TextView` that has Arabic text in it. But, the text is cut off, **this is how it's supposed to be:**

```
حلويّات
```

**How its showing:**

```
حلويّاتـ
```

Letters in arabic show like that (`تـ`) when they're **at the beginning of the sentence or at somewhere else other than the end**. More examples are in **different sentences**:

```
لعبتي
```

How it's showing (incorrect):

```
لعبتيـ
```

Here's an example TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:text="حلويّات"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Is there a way to do this without a custom font, since I have text EVERYWHERE and I have this problem?

Comment: please show your xml textview setup

Comment: @phongvan one sec

Comment: Could you try add android:textDirection="anyRtl" to XML ?

Comment: @phongvan what I gave you is just an example, my app is multi-language